# How does XCode compile properties without strong or weak attribute?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

What is Xcode compiling by default if I declare no `weak` or `strong` attribute to a `@property`?

For example, is

```
@property (nonatomic) CLLocation *location;
```

`strong` by default?

Comment: yes it is strong by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, **strong** by default, as stated in Apple's documentation.

> By default, object properties declared like this:
>
> ```
> @property id delegate;
> ```
>
> use **strong references** for their synthesized instance variables.

If you don't specify anything, as in the documentation example, the default is: `atomic, readwrite, strong`

Source: [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW30)

Comment: Thanks! It seems as I skipped the note ;-)

Answer (score 0):

About properties, if you didn't define attribute, the default is `strong`.

It's also same with the variable in function.

Ex: In your function, if you declare a local variable, default also `strong`

> NSString *hello = @"Hello World!";

If you want to use `weak`

> __weak NSString *hello = @"Hello World!";